# Is there a way to start further than the first with 2 local players?

Tags: ps3, far-cry-3

I'm trying to play Far Cry 3 co-op with 2 local players.

I don't want to start the offline mode from the very beginning.  In the *online* co-op mode, there is a `press start to enter` button to get the 2nd player into my game, but it takes another "account" on my PS3, and complains that the other account needs to be logged in.

Has anyone had any success finding a way to play co-op with 2 local players that doesn't involve starting offline mode all the way at the beginning?

Comment: It might deserve two distinct questions (one regarding the offline co-op issue, and another one for the online co-op issue) ;)

Comment: @Mike - I've changed the wording of this question because some people seemed to be confused by what you were asking.  If you disagree with this change, feel free to undo it yourself, or leave a comment and I'll undo it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out.

For co-op offline, select lets you pick a level while in the lobby.

For online, just make another profile on your PS3 (new user), use that profile to make another playstation network account.  It takes an email address, but you don't have to verify it.  Once that's done, the second player can press start in an online co-op lobby, and use the second PS3 account that's linked to the newly created Playstation network account.

Hope this helps someone else.